# How to merge an image to fill in other image with shape?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath, core-image

I want to merge an image to another image in one shape. Example:

1- People image
[image]

2- Shape Image: 
[image]

So how to do draw that. I already implement for merging but it's not fill to that shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this using the masking functions in the Quartz 2D framework. It's a little bit more involved than using the higher level image functions of UI Kit, but Quartz 2D gives you a lot more power to do cool graphics techniques.

The relevant Apple Developer guide to this can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html

For this example, you'd want to create a mask shape for the inside part of the shape image. There are two ways you can do this. One way is to use image editing software to create a second mask image, with the same size as your shape image, with pure black in the area where you want the people image to appear, and white where you don't want to appear. In this example, that would be the area inside the blue shape. It is important to not crop this image, or else they won't match up exactly.

The other way to create the masking image would be to do that dynamically based on the shape image, and honestly, this is the way I would do it. This would mean that you're including fewer images in your app, and if you made any changes to the shape image, you wouldn't have to recreate the mask image as well. You could do this by making a small change to the way your shape image is formatted. You would need to use a format that allows transparency - png is preferred - so that there is alpha transparency in the part of the image outside of the shape, which is white in your JPEG image. Make sure the section in the center of the image is white (really, any color that is NOT USED in the wanted part of the shape image would work, but I'll say white for this example) and that you don't have parts of it that aren't pure white after image compression.

You will then use Quartz to select the area that's white, and create a mask from that. This technique is a bit more involved, but what you need can be found in the document I linked to above. Because of this, you might start with a static masking image, and then convert to the more involved technique after you've got the code to make the first technique work.

When you have your masking image, you would create the mask itself with the function CGImageMaskCreate(*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:). You can then apply the mask to the people image using the function CGImageCreateWithMask(*:*:), which will give you an image with the person's portrait, with the correct shape cropped from the center.

Finally, you would display this in your app by placing the masked people image on top of the shape image, and voila, you'll have what you're looking for.

Also, keep in mind, when using the Quartz 2D framework, you'll have to make sure you release images when they are no longer needed, or else you could have memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, I have a clue